# Jquery anchor href affects whole site

Tags: jquery

I am new in jquery and am trying to use the jquery anchor code, which was written by Cedric Dugas for my site. It works well, but if I have a custom link, which does not use #, then that link won't be redirect to anywhere.

So, as far as i understand that the event.preventDefault() which blocks the google link to be opened and i don't know how to override this. Please help me! Thank you.

```js
/*******

 *** Anchor Slider by Cedric Dugas   ***
 *** Http://www.position-absolute.com ***
 
 Never have an anchor jumping your content, slide it.

 Don't forget to put an id to your anchor !
 You can use and modify this script for any project you want, but please leave this comment as credit.

 ~ MODIFIED! ~ 
 
*****/
  

jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

  settings = jQuery.extend({
  speed : 500,
  offset : 0
 }, settings); 
 
 return this.each(function(){
  var caller = this
  $(caller).click(function (event) { 
   event.preventDefault();
   var locationHref = window.location.href;
   var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href");
   
   var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top - settings.offset;

   if (destination < 0) {
    destination = 0;
   }

   $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
    
   });
     return false;
  })
 })
}
```

```html
<div> 
          <ul> 
              <li> 
                  <a href="#link1"> Homepage </a> 
              </li> 
          </ul>
          <ul> 
              <li> 
                  <a href="#link2"> Product </a> 
              </li> 
          </ul>
           <ul> 
              <li> 
                  <a href="#link3"> About us </a> 
              </li> 
          </ul>
</div>
<div>
         <ul> 
              <li> 
                  <a href="https://www.google.com"> Google link </a> 
              </li> 
          </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Include the part of your Javascript code where you bind the ancorAnimate function to your DOM nodes. The anchorAnimate function should be bound to relative anchors only,

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to check if the link is a has or not.

You can do this in many ways, I'm going to post one of the simplest ways.
You can simply surround the code block in this code `if($(caller).attr("href").charAt(0) == "#"){}`. It just simply checks if the first character in the href is a #, if it is, go ahead else do nothing.

```
jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

   settings = jQuery.extend({
      speed : 500,
      offset : 0
   }, settings);  

   return this.each(function(){
      var caller = this
      $(caller).click(function (event) {  
          if($(caller).attr("href").charAt(0) == "#"){
            event.preventDefault();
         var locationHref = window.location.href;
         var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href");

         var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top - settings.offset;

         if (destination < 0) {
            destination = 0;
         }

         $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {

         });
         return false;
        }
      })

   })
```

Comment: Cheers and happy coding! Dont forget to mark it as the answer for others.